# How do I make a loop animation stop and resume?

Tags: javascript, animation, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript code that I am going to use for an animated train map.
I have a loop that goes up and down, but I would like it to stop for 10 seconds every 20px, and then resume it's movement.
How do I accomplish this?

```
`window.onload = () => {
    startSetTrain0Animation();
    startSetTrain1Animation();
  };

  function startSetTrain0Animation() {
    const refreshRate = 1000 / 60;
    const maxXPosition = 470;
    let rect = document.getElementById('rect0');
    let speedX = 0.02;
    let positionX = 25;

    window.setInterval(() => {
      positionX = positionX + speedX;
      if (positionX > maxXPosition || positionX < 25) {
        speedX = speedX * (-1);
      }
      rect.style.top = positionX + 'px';
    }, refreshRate);

  }`
```

Comment: Use modulus to get the remainder of the total pixels divided by 20, then do `setTimeout` on whatever function you want to pause for 10 seconds

Comment: better to use requestAnimationFrame with css delay value

Answer (score 1):

There are typically two options to handle this:

- Use a flag to indicate the state of the loop
- Store a reference to the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function so that you can clear/stop via the [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearinterval) function and later restart.

### Using a Flag

Using a flag would be as simple as it sounds. Simply declare a variable and it would dictate if the body of the loop is executed or not:

```
// Flag to pause animation (change its value to toggle the animation)
var paused = false;

// Omitted for brevity
window.setInterval(() => {
  // If you are paused, don't do anything
  if (paused) {
     return;
  }

  positionX = positionX + speedX;
  if (positionX > maxXPosition || positionX < 25) {
    speedX = speedX * (-1);
  }
  rect.style.top = positionX + 'px';
}, refreshRate);
```

This is the simplest of use cases, however you could easily adjust it to define some logic regarding when you would start/stop within the interval itself.

### Explicitly Stopping / Restarting the Loop

Another option would be to store a reference to your loop in a variable when you declare it:

```
// Store a reference to your loop
var loop = setInterval(() => { ... }, refreshRate);

// Clear it when you need to stop it
window.clearInterval(loop);
```

If you prefer this approach, you'd likely elect to have a function that would wrap your "start loop" functionality such that you could do something like:

```
// Start the loop (wraps your setInterval() function)
var loop = startLoop();

// Stop the loop (could easily be renamed stopLoop())
window.clearInterval(loop);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `clearInterval` a method of the `window` object instead of the `setInterval` function?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I've adjusted it accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your quickl reply. I am not sure I fully understand the method (sorry I am VERY new to JS). I did enter your Flag example, but where exactly do I write how many px I want the animation to move before pausing? Do I need to do something with positionX?

Comment: Sure - my example wasn't necessarily geared towards the pixels moving, but what you could do is keep track of the number of pixels that have moved and after you hit a given condition (e.g. `paused = pixelsTraveled > 20`)` and then later and then based on n calls of your interval (depending on the refresh rate), you could designate when to unpause it and reset things if that makes sense.